# Querying direct children of root element with jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a problem with matching direct children of a root element using jsonpath. Having such a data:

```
{"name": "lorem", "age": 15}
```

How can I check if this json has a field "name" with value "lorem"?. I tried something like this:

```
$[?(@.name == "lorem")]
```

but it returns an empty array, because (I guess) it search for a field "name" deeper in the structure. So I tried:

```
$[?(@ == "lorem")]
```

But it didn't work also (incorrect syntax)

However - it works, when queried field is "deeper" in json structure. With this json data:

```
{"name": {"realName": "lorem"}, "age": 15}
```

this query works as expected, returning non-empty result:

```
$[?(@.realName == "lorem")]
```

It seems like there is no possibility to perform similar query for fields that are direct children of root element. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to indicate what language and implementation you are using. JSONPath was a helpful beginning, but informal and underspecified.

Using [jsonpath-plus](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath), you *can* use `@` to check the value at root, but if you want to ensure you are on the correct property, you will also need to use its custom `@property` value:

```
var json = {"name": "lorem", "age": 15};
var path = '$[?(@property == "name" && @ == "lorem")]';
JSONPath({json: json, path: path, wrap: false});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vq1dm792/