# How to use @odata.count property in JSONPath expression?

Tags: json, odata, soapui, jsonpath

Using the following JSON object from a response of a OData v4 API:

```
{

   "@odata.context": "https://api.asdfasdf.com/",
   "@odata.count": 2,
   "value": [
        {
            "id": 123456789,
            "name": "Random name"
        },
        {
            "id": 15345,
            "name": "Random name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works to select the object in the array:
`$.value[?(@.id == 123456789)]`

With this JSONPath I can get the value of the property "@odata.count":
`$.['@odata.count']`

But how to write JSONPath with expressions using the "@odata.count"?
For example. selecting only if the count is greater than 1, these expressions fail:

```
$.[('@odata.count' > 1)]
$.[?('@odata.count' > 1)]
$.[(@.['@odata.count'] > 1)]
... and a lot of other expressions
```

I strongly believe I'm working on a different depth of the json than I think,
and the naming convention of the property (and manner of selecting it) drives me nuts.

The ultimate goal is to use the expression in a SoapUI Testsuite assertion.

Comparing the "@odata.count" propery in the response against our test data.

**Edit:**
Fixed json by removing quotes after the number, thanks to commenter.

And additional findings of expressions that helped me finding the solution:

These expressions results in '2':

```
$['@odata.count']
$..[0]['@odata.count']
```

This expression results in an empty array:

```
$..[?(@['@odata.count'] > 1)]
```

This expressions results in the value 'null':

```
?($['@odata.count'] > 1)
```

**Edit 2:**
This question should have been asked slightly more general I think, it's more about "how to use root properties/root attributes/direct children of the response in JSONPath".
A similar question I found, with a total different answer: [Querying direct children of root element with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843690/querying-direct-children-of-root-element-with-jsonpath/36854660)

Comment: Invalid JSON. I think your  line with "id": 15345", should be  "id": 15345,

Comment: Are you using java?

Comment: I answered myself in the end, but can't vote for it. I use these expressions in a JSONPath expression within SoapUI. SoapUI uses [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy) but I'm not sure if that's also used to parse the provided JSONPath expression in the assertions within a test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the following works for me:

`$..[?(@.['@odata.count'] > 1)]`

It gives me the same array as the expression `$..` (an array containing the json response).
What it does, according to my own findings:

`$..[]` - looks into the array containing the response

`?(@.['@odata.count'] > 1)` - pick the array item containing a property with a value greater than 1

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
I only don't understand the difference that makes the third dot, the eight character. I thought it's not needed when using bracket notation which is required here due to the name of the attribute.

Looking at the ultimate goal of using it in an assertion of a test suite in SoapUI, the following is probaly more readible and customizable in the long run (should have looked into this soloution with `groovy` 4 hours earlier...):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
odatacount = "${jsonResponse.'@odata.count'}"
assert odatacount > 1
```